# Storing a type in a struct for compare

Tags: go, testing

Given the following code: I'm trying to store the type of the mongo client in the struct to later be compared.

```
func TestGetMongoClient(t *testing.T) {
    type args struct {
        opts *Options
    }
    tests := []struct {
        name    string
        args    args
        want    *mongo.Client
        wantErr bool
    }{
        {name: "Mongo Client Creation", args: args{opts: &opts}, want: , wantErr: nil},
    }
    for _, tt := range tests {
        t.Run(tt.name, func(t *testing.T) {
            got, err := GetMongoClient(tt.args.opts)
            if (err != nil) != tt.wantErr {
                t.Errorf("GetMongoClient() error = %v, wantErr %v", err, tt.wantErr)
                return
            }
            typeCompare = reflect.TypeOf(tt.want) == reflect.TypeOf(got)
            if typeCompare {
                t.Errorf("GetMongoClient() = %v, want %v", got, tt.want)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Prior, I had the following code which worked well however I have to translate it into a table based testing structure.

```
func TestGetMongoConnection(t *testing.T) {
    client, err := GetMongoClient(&opts)
    if err != nil {
        t.Errorf("GetMongoConnect should not return an error but did %d", err)
    }
    result := reflect.TypeOf(&client) == reflect.TypeOf((**mongo.Client)(nil))
    if result == false {
        t.Errorf("Calling GetMongoConnection didn't return a client %d", err)
    }
}
```

How can I get the table based code to work well?

Comment: Not sure I follow: won't `want: &mongo.Client{}` work? or is mongo.Client and interface?

Comment: @TehSphinX Basically, I'm just trying to test if what is returned is an instance of mongo.Client or in this specific case the same type

Comment: @Quesofat Is `GetMongoClient` declared to return a value of type `*mongo.Client`?

Comment: Than that should do: &mongo.Client{}

Comment: @CeriseLimón Yes, GetMongoClient returns a value of type *mongo.Client

Comment: @TehSphinX Great. Can you post this as an answer?

Comment: @Quesofat I am confused by the goal of your test.  If the function is declared to return a value type `*mongo.Client`, then you can be assured that the return value is of that type.  There's no need to test it.

Comment: @CeriseLimón: unless you want to make sure, that no one ever changes the return type of the function. Then this test would fail.

Comment: @TehSphinX and likely the entire application would fail to compile, preventing the test from even running.

Comment: Type inference exists for a reason. If your application depends on the specific return type, then if that type is changed then it will just fail to compile, as @Adrian says. If it doesn't depend on the specific return type, then there's no point writing an unnecessary test for the sole purpose of creating such a dependency.

Comment: @Adrian: IDEs are getting smarter and smarter and learn to automatically correct the type of return values. Goland for example can already do that to a large extend. Cerise Limón's answer might lead to a compile error today, but maybe not any more in a year or two.

Comment: Not saying, that I would use the reflect check for the type. I don't really see the point, but @Quesofat might have his/her reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To compare the type returned from a function to be the same type you want, just declare a new variable with the same type and use `reflect.TypeOf` to compare:

```golang
type Client struct {
    id string
}

func GetClient() *Client {
    return &Client{id: "bla"}
}

func main() {
    want := &Client{}

    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(want) == reflect.TypeOf(GetClient()))
    // prints: true
}
```

So in your case, `want` should be declared as `&mongo.Client{}`.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following code to assert that return values of `GetClient` have the types `*mongo.Client, error`:

```
var got *mongo.Client
var err error
got, err = GetMongoClient(tt.args.opts)
```

The code compiles with an error if `GetMongoClient` is changed to return different types.